# Vuetify 3 - The position of the dropdown from the v-select is wrong

Tags: css, vuetify.js, v-select

I have a small problem with Vuetify 3.
The **dropdown **from the **select **is moved to the right when I first open it. The second time I open it, it is displayed correctly under the item.

```
        <v-select
            variant="solo"
            :items="anzahlTeams"
            v-model="tNumberTeams"
            label="Anzahl Teams"
            density="compact"
        ></v-select>
```

Here is a screenshot.

[image: Select with drowdown]

I also can't check the element in the browser (DevTools) because it closes directly when clicked.
[image: Browser, DevTools]
[image: Brwoser, DevTools2]

## **Can anyone tell me what the problem could be?**

Comment: I face the same issue, did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: @Xanthous 
i think the problem is with the CSS command "margin".
either you set the the margin  of the element around to auto of 0:

margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
or 
margin: 10px auto;